# Mail sent with sp_send_dbmail shows embedded images as attachments

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, html-email, sp-send-dbmail

I'm using `sp_send_dbmail` to send a "welcome" email to employees' newly provisioned mailboxes. The content looks good in both Outlook 2016 and in Office365.

There is a difference from the source email I'm replicating, however, in the how the attachments appear. The source email does not show a paperclip icon or attachments in either system. The email sent with `sp_send_dbmail` shows the paperclip in both and lists attachments in Office365 (but not in Outlook).

I copied the HTML from the source email in Outlook and had to change the `src` tags to get it to work:

```
<img ... src="cid:image009.png@01D42E2D.8043A5B0">
```

This wouldn't show the images until I removed the `@01D42E2D.8043A5B0`. I haven't been able to find any explanation of what that part of the tag does or how to use it properly.

Is there a way to make the message sent with `sp_send_dbmail` appear exactly as the original does?

**Edit to add:**
Further testing finds that TypeApp (an Android mail client) doesn't render the images from `sp_send_dbmail`, but it does display the source email correctly.

I realize that email clients won't behave consistently, but why can't I make the email I send behave like the other?

Answer (score 0):

A *possible* workaround is to use SendGrid email.  It might work differently with embedded images. Not sure.

In a previous project I hit a lot of various problems with our internal Exchange server, so I just went outside to SendGrid, which worked very well. They have a free tier.